# Strange exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I get this exception: Message =

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

This is the code I have:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeValue, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

The weird thing is I went through the debugger, and when `timeValue = "01-02-2015 10:00:00.000"` for example, all is Ok. 
If `timeValue = "02-02-2015  10:00:00.000"` I get this exception. I am quite confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the issue is multiple spaces between date and time part, use:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("02-02-2015  10:00:00.000", 
                    "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite);
```

Comment: pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`, `null` would assume current culture and you may run into exception due to date time separator.